# Verify $index and set a style

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-class

Im trying to highlight a table line, but its hard to translate to angular js inside of the directive. Check the pseudo code:

```
if(highlight.indexOf($index) != -1) set .highlight css class
```

This is an example of my code:

```js
$scope.highlight  = [0,2,3]
```

```css
.highlight {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<table class="ui celled table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>AAA</th>
      <th>BBB</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="a in as track by $index"> <!-- The ng-class needs to be here, but where should i do the verification? -->
      <td>{{a}}</td>
      <td>{{b[$index]}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`ng-class`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) after the `ng-repeat`:

```
<tr ng-repeat="a in as track by $index" ng-class="{highlight: highlight.indexOf($index) > -1}">
```